# htaccess for only Apple Users

Tags: .htaccess

What's the most elegant way to allow only Apple OS users onto a website and redirect all others to  default page?

The following seems kind of award.

BrowserMatchNoCase Windows bad_os
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=bad_os

ErrorDocument 403 http://me.com/pc.html

Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all

Comment: It will seem kind of awkward because - with all due respect - it's kind of an absurd idea. You can try all these hacks but webservers and HTML itself are designed to be inclusive of different platforms, not exclusive.

Comment: I agree with you in general but I wouldn't ask if I didn't have a good reason to keep windows out.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to use the `BrowserMatchNoCase` directive, which will allow you to do a case insensitive search of the user agent environment variable.  I.e.,

```
BrowserMatchNoCase apple platform=macintosh
BrowserMatchNoCase mac platform=macintosh
[etc..]

RewriteCond %{ENV:platform} !macintosh
# Don't actually rewrite to anything (-); just return 403
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

(as taken from the [mod_setenvif documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_setenvif.html#browsermatchnocase)).  You can then use this variable to redirect to different pages.  This would be cleaner if you have many conditions to check (and I have no idea how many you will need).  If you have only a few, or want to chain them together in what could become a potentially messy string, you could use `mod_rewrite` directly.  The following insures that `apple` and `mac` are not in the user agent, and redirects non-matching requests.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !apple [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !mac [NC]
[etc..]
# Don't actually rewrite to anything (-); just return 403
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

This uses the `[NC]` flag for RewriteCond which indicates that the searches be case insensitive--again, a necessity if you're not sure what conditions you'll be matching.  The `F` flag in the RewriteRule will return a 403 Forbidden.

Pay heed to Robert Moir's comment, though, because this relies on the browser sending a matching user agent--which isn't even close to being reliable.  This should get you started, and you can additional matches as you find them.

Andrew

Comment: Andrew thanks. That seems to be what I'm looking for. Not being the programmer you think I am, what do I need around it to make this work? How would a sample look like sending Windows user to a default page. Do you know or can you guide me further?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your request.  Also provided alternative method using `RewriteCond` from mod_rewrite.  I haven't tested these to the dot, but they should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Great, gonna have a go at it and test this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite and check HTTP_USER_AGENT, you will need a list of iOS user-agents.

Also, theres something called Apache Mobile Filter: http://www.idelfuschini.it/it/apache-mobile-filter-v2x.html

I have not used it yet, but looks nice.

Comment: Thanks for the link, the answer seems to be deep down there. Will check it.